# How to increase/decrease number when Press the button?

Tags: java, android

I have two buttons: 1 and 2. The button 1 is used to increase a number from 0 to 15 and button 2 is used to decrease, with input is the current value of the number to 0.

Assume that initial value of the number is =-1. Then I press the button 1,  the number will increase to 1 value (0). If I press 5 times, the current number value is 4. Then I press the button 2, the values will decrease from 5

```
For example, 
Button 1 press                         Button 2 press
0
1
2
3
4
                                               4
                                               3
                                               2
                                               ...
```

If the value is smaller than 0, then set button 2 is disabled, if the value is bigger than 15, set button 1 is disabled. I used below code but it does not work well. Could you tell me what is happen?

```
 int number=-1;
 public void onClickBtn1 (View v)
    {        
        number++;
        btn2.setEnabled(true);
        if(number>=16) {
            number = 16;
            btn1.setEnabled(false);
        }

        if(number<=15) {            
            Log.d("TAG", number);
        }
    }
    public void onClickBtn2 (View v)
    {
        btnTop.setEnabled(true);
        number--;
        if(number<=-1) {
            number =-1;
            btn2.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(number>=0) {            
            Log.d("TAG",number);
        }
    }
```

**Update:** Now, I can print as 0 to 5 (press button 1) and (5 to 0) when press button 2. But the code look complex and the button disable does not work when the number is over than 15 (<=16), and less than 0(>=-1)

My code is

```
int number=-1;
 public void onClickBtn1 (View v)
    {        
        btn2.setEnabled(true);
        if(number<=-1) {
            number =-1;
        }
        number++;
        if(number>=16) {
            number = 16;
            btn1.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(number<=15) {
            Log.d("TAG",number);
        }
    }
    public void onClickBtn2 (View v)
    {
        btn1.setEnabled(true);

        if(number<=-1) {
            number =-1;
            btn2.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(number>=16) {
            number = 15;
            btn1.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(number>=0) {        
            Log.d("TAG",number);
        }
        number--;
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Define 'does not work well'

Comment: The number show does not as my expected. It show 0....4 and 3..2...

Comment: I think it is from number --;

Comment: Are you saying that if the last number printed was 4, and you press button 2, you want it to print 4 again before it starts decreasing?

Comment: Right. It is exactly what I need. And the button enable and disable when number over 16 and 0

Comment: Then just move your `if(number>=0){...}` before `number--;`. But I don't understand why do you need that. Your code decrements the `number` variable when button2 is pressed then it compares it to 0 and executes code inside of `if`

Comment: Then just move the print line to before the decrement line in `onClickBtn2`, and it will work swimmingly.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Print line must be end sir

Comment: No, really it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Here is simple logic.

```
Button add, remove;
TextView value;
int temp = 0;
int lastClicked = -1;
int ADD = 1;
int REMOVE = 2;


    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (lastClicked == REMOVE) {
                lastClicked = ADD;
                return;
            }
            if (temp < 15) {
                temp++;
                add.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                temp = 15;
            }
            if (temp == 15) {
                add.setEnabled(false);
            }
            if (temp > 0) {
                remove.setEnabled(true);
            }
            lastClicked = ADD;
            value.setText("" + temp);
        }
    });
    remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (lastClicked == ADD) {
                lastClicked = REMOVE;
                return;
            }
            if (temp > 0) {
                temp--;
                remove.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                temp = 0;
            }
            if (temp == 0) {
                remove.setEnabled(false);
            }
            if (temp < 15) {
                add.setEnabled(true);
            }
            lastClicked = REMOVE;
            value.setText("" + temp);
        }
    });
```

it should be enough for your issue.
let me know if any issue.

Comment: It is still from 0 to 5 when press button 1 and 4 to 0 when press button 2, instead of 5 to 0

Comment: I think you are understand what I need. However, when I press the button 2, the start value is still 4 to 0 instead of 5 to 0. You can download my code at https://www.dropbox.com/s/scvlzpjrcyzo36g/TestIncrease.zip?dl=0

Comment: I have updated code just 10 min ago. It works for 0 and 15. Not 1->4 and 4->1. unless you replace 15 with 4. I'll have look at your code.

Comment: Again Please check I've updated code to work with any number from 0 to 15.

Comment: Right, It is from 0 to 15 now. But the second button does not from a highest value when it decrease. For example, I am in 5, then press second button, it must show 5 and decrease from 5. You are 0,4,...

Comment: Just use two textview as my code to see what is happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123513/discussion-between-deardhruv-and-user8430).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to achieve. Try this.

```
public void onClickBtn1 (View v)
{        
    number++;
    btn2.setEnabled(true);

    if(number==15) {
        btn1.setEnabled(false);
    }

    Log.d("TAG", number);
}

public void onClickBtn2 (View v)
{
    btn1.setEnabled(true);
    number--;
    if(number==0) {
        btn2.setEnabled(false);
    }           

    Log.d("TAG",number);
}
```

Comment: It is not correct. It is from 0 to 5 but press button 2 is from 4 to 0 instead of 5 to 0

Comment: Of course thats how it works. When you press minus it should display 4 because 5-1 = 4. Its like from 100volume you press volume down, it doesnt display 100. It displays 99. Set your `number=0;` Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question following may be the solution

global variables

```
public final String BUTTON1 = "button1", BUTTON2 = "button2";
TextView button2;
int number = 0;
String lastButtonClicked = "button1";
```

and your `buttonClickListeners`

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        button2.setEnabled(true);
        if (lastButtonClicked.equals(BUTTON1) && number < 15)
            number++;
        lastButtonClicked = BUTTON1;
        if (number == 15) {
            button1.setEnabled(false);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "" + number);
    }
});
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        button1.setEnabled(true);
        if (lastButtonClicked.equals(BUTTON2) && number > 0)
            number--;
        lastButtonClicked = BUTTON2;
        if (number == 0) {
            button2.setEnabled(false);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "" + number);
    }
});
button2.setEnabled(false);
Log.d("TAG", "" + 0);
```

Comment: No, this has the same problem as the other two answers here.

Comment: @indramurari: I was busy. I am checking

Comment: @indramurari: My number start from 0. when click the button 1. Your code is from 1

Comment: @user8430 that's ok initialise number with -1

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button1, button2;
int number = -1, initial = -1;

button2.setEnabled(false); // initially setting button2 disable

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(number < 15) {
                number++;
            }
//this is because: If the value is smaller than 0, then set button 2 is disabled -> enabling if > 0
            if(number > 0) {
                button2.setEnabled(true);
            }

            if(number == 15){
                button1.setEnabled(false);  //because of range: from 0 to 15
            }

        }
    });

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            button1.setEnabled(true);

// below condition is for: (Then I press the button 1, the number will increase to 1 value (0). If I press 5 times, the current number value is 4. Then I press the button 2, the values will decrease from 5)

//and initial value is -1 for once, as I think you didn't need to  check it later because range is 0-15 but initially you are taking -1.

            if(initial == -1){

                number = number - initial;
                initial = 0; // changed the value
            }


            if(number > 0) {
                number--;
            }

//as your range is 0-15, so can't be less than 0

            if(number == 0){
                button2.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int number = -1;
int total;
Button plus, minus;
TextView textViewTotal;
private static String TAG="MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
    minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);
    textViewTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);

    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            total = number;
            if(number == 15) {
                plus.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                number++;
                plus.setEnabled(true);
                textViewTotal.setText(String.valueOf(number));
            }
            if (number > 0) {
                minus.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });

    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            total = number;
            if(number < -1) {
                minus.setEnabled(false);
                plus.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                minus.setEnabled(true);
                plus.setEnabled(true);
                number --;
                textViewTotal.setText(String.valueOf(number+1));
                if (total == number) {
                    number--;
                    textViewTotal.setText(String.valueOf(number));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}